# Does Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 support Windows Push Notification Services (WNS)?

Tags: push-notification, windows-phone-8.1

I have a WP SL8.1 project, can I use WNS with it? I checked some documents, it's said that only Windows Runtime App can use WNS, is that so?

Comment: could you give the link? `some documents` is vague.

Comment: Here is [what I found](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202940%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), it states **Applies to :** `Windows Phone 8 and Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1`

Comment: Thank you, and my problem is here: my SL8.1 project used PushNotificationChannel API, it works very well util I submit the App to Windows Phone Store, it failed in Supported API test, I got some info as below:This API is not supported for this application type - Api=Windows.Networking.PushNotifications.PushNotificationChannel. Module=. File=xxxxxx.dll.

Comment: Sorry, I was confused by `Microsoft Push Notification Services (MPNS)` and `Windows Push Notification Services (WNS)` and edited your question too many times.

Comment: 1) is WNS supported and 2) I'm having a problem with WNS are two different questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use either MPNS or WNS with SL8.1. Follow the instructions here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn642085(v=vs.105).aspx.

The article you linked to is documentation for MPNS and so the APIs will not work with WNS.

Comment: If you want Sl8.1 support WNS, you must choose "WNS" as Notification Service in WMAppManifest.xml, then this way, RawNotification API can be passed by WP Store validation.

Comment: I must say that changing to WNS as Notification Service may take some risks, if you already have a old version for your app which it used secondary Tile in WP Store, after upgrade, your secondary Tile will be changed to Main Tile. It maybe a Microsoft's bug, but anyway be careful!